# Is it possible to run 2 concurrent tcpdump with different options?

Tags: linux, mysql, tcp, tcpdump, packet-capture

I need to run 2 concurrent `tcpdump` commands with different arguments/options. Why ? Because we wrote some long long scripts compatible with following options :

```
tcpdump -ixenbr0 -s 400 -n -A 'port sip || (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420) || (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x504f5354 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 4:1] = 0x20) || (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x48545450 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 4:4] = 0x2f312e31 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 8:4] = 0x20323030 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 12:2] = 0x204f && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 14:1] = 0x4b)' > tcpdump.txt
```

These options and formatting are needed for our script (those strange rules are needed to filter GET, POST and SIP protocol packets only). In the other I need to capture MySQL packets and analyze them. As its not a trivial task to find [request/responses and analyze the mean time of execution of the queries](https://serverfault.com/questions/709205/capture-all-mysql-requests-responses-and-caculate-the-response-time-using-tcpdum), so I planned to use [pt-query-digest package](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) to analyze SQL queries using tcpdump, but it requires to execute the tcpdump with the following option and it won't work in other formats:

```
tcpdump  -ixenbr0 -s 65535 -n -x -q -tttt port 3306 > tcpdump.txt
```

Is it possible to run two concurrent `tcpdumps` OR any way to have tcpdump output in both formats mentioned OR is there anyway to merge these two commands?

Comment: What happens when you simply try to?

Comment: @HBruijn sorry didn't get you. What happens when try what?

Comment: Run them concurrently I mean.

Comment: @HBruijn Ok, It works :) ... I thought it won't work and it will have conflicts...but is it a good idea to have 2 tcpdumps running at the same time ? in terms of performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. It won't cause conflicts at all.